# Auto rebin the histogram in plotly express based on active Colors

Tags: python, plotly, histogram, plotly-express

With `plotly.express.histogram`, is there a way to force rebinning when I unselect one or more `colors (metrics)` under comparison?

The following code gives me the images below (but in interactive mode)

```py
import plotly.express as px
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

dfA = pd.DataFrame({'Value': np.random.normal(0, 100, 1000)}).assign(Metric='A')
dfB = pd.DataFrame({'Value': np.random.normal(1000, 500, 1000)}).assign(Metric='B')

px.histogram(pd.concat([dfA, dfB]), color='Metric', barmode='overlay').show()
px.histogram(dfA, color='Metric', barmode='overlay').show()
```

[image: dfA & dfB Together]
[image: dfA Alone]

However, when I unselect B from the first plot, I get

[image: dfA & dfB but dfB unselected]

This is different from what I get when I plot dfA alone. Probably because the number of bins is untouched, **while the X (and Y) axis are recalibrated**.

Is there a way to force rebinning based on the current selection?

Answer (score 1):

Yes, the histograms here share the same [`bingroup`](https://plotly.com/python/reference/histogram/#histogram-bingroup), and basically you want to remove hidden(s) traces from that bingroup to force rebinning for the remaining/visible trace(s).

Since interactive renderers display figures using plotly.js, you can actually *use* javascript+plotly.js to hook into the [`plotly_legendclick`](https://plotly.com/javascript/plotlyjs-events/#legend-click-events) event and override the default behavior. To achieve this, you just need to pass the javascript code as a string to plotly's `Figure.show()` method via the [`post_script`](https://plotly.github.io/plotly.py-docs/generated/plotly.html#plotly.basedatatypes.BaseFigure.to_html) parameter :

```py
dfA = pd.DataFrame({'Value': np.random.normal(0, 100, 1000)}).assign(Metric='A')
dfB = pd.DataFrame({'Value': np.random.normal(1000, 500, 1000)}).assign(Metric='B')

fig = px.histogram(pd.concat([dfA, dfB]), color='Metric', barmode='overlay')
bingroup = fig.data[0].bingroup

js = f'const bingroup = "{bingroup}";' + '''
const gd = document.getElementById('{plot_id}');

gd.on('plotly_legendclick', function(eventData) {
    const i = eventData.curveNumber;
    const trace = eventData.fullData[i];
    const update = {};

    if (trace.visible === true) {
        update.visible = 'legendonly';
        update.bingroup = '';
    }
    else {
        update.visible = true;
        update.bingroup = bingroup;
    }

    Plotly.restyle(gd, update, [i]);
    return false;
});
'''

fig.show(post_script=[js])
```

Comment: It works like a charm, but its too much code for a beginner with Plotly, is there an easier way for someone like me without using JS?

Comment: Yeah it's probably not very straightforward if you are not comfortable with JS/Plotly.js,  but no I don't think there is another way to do that. If you need explanations about the code used, feel free to ask here in the comments or in another question if you think it deserves its own post.