# How do I make interacting updates?

Tags: python, plotly, plotly-python

The [Plotly Documentation on Dropdowns](https://plotly.com/python/dropdowns/) contains the following example:

```py
import plotly.graph_objects as go

import pandas as pd

# Load dataset
df = pd.read_csv(
    "https://raw.githubusercontent.com/plotly/datasets/master/finance-charts-apple.csv")
df.columns = [col.replace("AAPL.", "") for col in df.columns]

# Initialize figure
fig = go.Figure()

# Add Traces

fig.add_trace(
    go.Scatter(x=list(df.Date),
               y=list(df.High),
               name="High",
               line=dict(color="#33CFA5")))

fig.add_trace(
    go.Scatter(x=list(df.Date),
               y=[df.High.mean()] * len(df.index),
               name="High Average",
               visible=False,
               line=dict(color="#33CFA5", dash="dash")))

fig.add_trace(
    go.Scatter(x=list(df.Date),
               y=list(df.Low),
               name="Low",
               line=dict(color="#F06A6A")))

fig.add_trace(
    go.Scatter(x=list(df.Date),
               y=[df.Low.mean()] * len(df.index),
               name="Low Average",
               visible=False,
               line=dict(color="#F06A6A", dash="dash")))

# Add Annotations and Buttons
high_annotations = [dict(x="2016-03-01",
                         y=df.High.mean(),
                         xref="x", yref="y",
                         text="High Average:<br> %.3f" % df.High.mean(),
                         ax=0, ay=-40),
                    dict(x=df.Date[df.High.idxmax()],
                         y=df.High.max(),
                         xref="x", yref="y",
                         text="High Max:<br> %.3f" % df.High.max(),
                         ax=-40, ay=-40)]
low_annotations = [dict(x="2015-05-01",
                        y=df.Low.mean(),
                        xref="x", yref="y",
                        text="Low Average:<br> %.3f" % df.Low.mean(),
                        ax=0, ay=40),
                   dict(x=df.Date[df.High.idxmin()],
                        y=df.Low.min(),
                        xref="x", yref="y",
                        text="Low Min:<br> %.3f" % df.Low.min(),
                        ax=0, ay=40)]

fig.update_layout(
    updatemenus=[
        dict(
            active=0,
            buttons=list([
                dict(label="None",
                     method="update",
                     args=[{"visible": [True, False, True, False]},
                           {"title": "Yahoo",
                            "annotations": []}]),
                dict(label="High",
                     method="update",
                     args=[{"visible": [True, True, False, False]},
                           {"title": "Yahoo High",
                            "annotations": high_annotations}]),
                dict(label="Low",
                     method="update",
                     args=[{"visible": [False, False, True, True]},
                           {"title": "Yahoo Low",
                            "annotations": low_annotations}]),
                dict(label="Both",
                     method="update",
                     args=[{"visible": [True, True, True, True]},
                           {"title": "Yahoo",
                            "annotations": high_annotations + low_annotations}]),
            ]),
        )
    ])

# Set title
fig.update_layout(title_text="Yahoo")

fig.show()
```

I would like to have two dropdowns instead, one for "High Visible" and the other for "Low Visible", and the title should be "Yahoo, High: {yes or no}, Low: {yes or no}", but neither internet searches nor ChatGPT can suggest how to change visibility of frames/traces depending on the current values of other dropdowns.

This is a somewhat contrived example; in my actual use case, I have three sliders with 8, 8, and 51 options respectively, and I don't want to create a single slider with 3264 values.

Comment: I don't quite understand your purpose. Is it to create a 'High Visible' button and a 'Low Visible' button to replace the dropdowns you have now?

Comment: @r-beginners yes

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The thing is it's not possible (with updatemenus) to have a dropdown button acting *given the state of* another dropdown, ie. the button `args` are static where you need them to be dynamic.

You would need a function callback instead for handling input changes and make the dropdowns work in conjunction by building the `{"visible": [...]}` argument dynamically, and then call plotly.js "update" method manually with this argument. You could do it this way by adding some javascript to the rendered html, that is, by passing a `post_script` via the `show()` method, @see examples [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/77091561/2529954) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/76818446/2529954)).

Or, you could use [Dash](https://dash.plotly.com/) which allows to build rich layouts with interactions, it provides many components (including [dropdowns](https://dash.plotly.com/dash-core-components/dropdown)), and runs a server (ie. so you can have backend [callbacks](https://dash.plotly.com/basic-callbacks) updating the layout and Plotly figures, I mean no javascript required although you can still have clientside callbacks).